# Prisma migration error: The database schema is not empty

Tags: prisma

I have a prisma db and I am trying to run the deploy command for production.

When running yarn rw prisma migrate deploy , I get an error saying:

```
1 migration found in prisma/migrations

Error: P3005

The database schema is not empty. Read more about how to baseline an existing production database: https://pris.ly/d/migrate-baseline
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried baselining the database? This [link](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/baselining) on baselining should help.

Comment: Hey @jessica, did you find an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 9):

If you setted up Prisma on an existing database you must skip initial migration as such:

```
yarn prisma migrate resolve --applied <migration_name>
```

Its called [baselining](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/baselining).

If it doesnt work due to some existing data, you can either rollback changes or fix the data problem and apply a fix with `yarn prisma migrate diff`

Details are [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/production-troubleshooting#fixing-failed-migrations-with-migrate-diff-and-db-execute).

I ran the `diff` and applied the resulting file as such:

```
yarn prisma migrate diff --from-url <DATABASE_URL_PROD> --to-schema-datamodel <path to schema.prisma> --script > forward.sql
```

```
yarn prisma db execute --url <DATABASE_URL_PROD> --file forward.sql
```

Comment: you just saved me multiple hours of configuration problems

Comment: It's called 'blessing'!